# How to debug websocket client losing connection and reestablishing it

Tags: node.js, networking, websocket, connection

I'm using node.js, websockets/ws.

In my site sometimes a random client loses connection without losing connection to other internet stuff. Less then a second later they connect back, with a new socket. (There is a code that calls socket.onClose, which tries to reconnect back to server)

On the server side I can't see or log anything wrong. Everything looks like a normal disconnect, same as closing the browser tab.

I am guessing the reason is either socket related or client related but I don't know where to begin to debug this problem.

I got ping/pong responses with 60 second timer, this isn't it. The user usually loses connection while active.

How can I debug this problem and find the reason?

I keep all the session info, data, within the socket and that is why I do not want people to lose their connection.

Thanks

Comment: If you're using socket.io it should fallback to http, reconnect, etc..

Comment: Also there is `disconnect` event on server side, maybe it might help you.

Comment: @Lazyexpert I'm using websockets/ws, nothing in the server side helped me

Comment: If you're talking about this one: https://www.npmjs.com/package/websockets , there is event `closed` on socket, server-side.

Comment: If you're using this package, I advice you to switch to more popular solution.

Comment: https://github.com/websockets/ws I am using this. And I am checking the onClosed method. It just doesn't give me any significant info. Yes the socket is being closed, yes server knows about it, but it looks like any other socket closing event. So I can see no differentiator as why the user may have lost the connection, is it a bug on my end, or users end, or the library?